# explicit template specialization for std::complex<T>

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a template function, which return a vector of data.  Now I try to use it with std::complex, but I need a explicit template specialization version of it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> FillData(unsigned int n)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    return v;
}

template<>
std::vector<std::complex<double>> FillData(unsigned int n)
{
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> v;
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
auto v1 = FillData<float>(10);
auto v2 = FillData<int>(10);
auto v3 = FillData<std::complex<double>>(10);
auto v4 = FillData<std::complex<float>>(10);  // call the one not expected
}
```

My question is, how can I specialize the template with different type of std::complex?  Do I need one explicit specialization for each type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either need an explicit instantiation for each type, or you need to use SFINAE to detect that `T` is actually a `std::complex<U>`, or you need to use structs so you can do partial specialization. Functions cannot be partially specialized

Comment: This is for sure a dupe...

Answer (score 1):

Forward to a class that you can partial specialize:

```
template <typename T>
struct FillDataHelper
{
    std::vector<T> operator () () const { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
struct FillDataHelper<std::complex<T>>
{
    std::vector<std::complex<T>> operator () () const { return {}; }
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> FillData(unsigned int n)
{
    return FillDataHelper<T>{}();
}
```

Comment: There are many functions doing different works.  I would prefer the other override solution which need less change.  Thanks.

Comment: @TigerHwang If you have a lot of cases, that’s an argument for this solution. If you ever need to do something different for a non-template type, this method will work but the other one won’t.

Answer (score 1):

pass a model of the vector you want filled by value, and then let <strike>RVO</strike> the as-if rule return it back to you with almost no overhead.

You can now overload the FillData function if you need different behaviour depending on T.

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> FillData(std::vector<T> v, unsigned int n)
{
    v.reserve(n);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++n)
    {
        // for example
        v.push_back(0);
    }
    return v;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::complex<T>> FillData(std::vector<std::complex<T>> v, unsigned int n)
{
    v.reserve(n);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++n)
    {
        // for example
        v.push_back(std::complex<T>(1, 0));
    }
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto v1 = FillData(std::vector<float>(), 10);
    auto v2 = FillData(std::vector<int>(), 10);
    auto v3 = FillData(std::vector<std::complex<double>>(), 10);
    auto v4 = FillData(std::vector<std::complex<float>>(), 10);
}
```

Comment: Better to pass a tag than a dummy instance: `template <typename> struct tag {}; std::vector<T> FillData(tag<T>, unsigned int n);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 passing a model has no overhead and allows for the fact that the model might already have data in it.

Comment: RVO doesn't work here because v is an argument.

Comment: @juanchopanza struggling to see any performance loss here: https://godbolt.org/g/whGiA4

Comment: I just said RVO doesn't apply. "as if" still does, and also v can be moved.

Comment: This is nice.  Let me try how to put tag into it.

Comment: So this is actually overload of template, there are two templates, one for general type and one for std::complex<> type.  It's not template specialization anymore.

Comment: This is a bad idea if you have other specializations; overloading and specialization don’t mix well.

Comment: @TigerHwang one for std::vector<T>, one for std::vector<std::complex<T>> - each one if declaring an infinite set of overloads, but the signatures of the two sets can never overlap.

Comment: @DanielH specialising template functions is never a good idea. Overloading or deferring to a specialised function object is always a superior solution.

Comment: @RichardHodges Why do you say that? Overloading doesn’t always work and I don’t see why deferring to a function object is superior to specialization.

Comment: @DanielH there's an informative piece on it here: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @RichardHodges So basically to allow you to do partial or complete specialization if you want. But again, that doesn’t show any problems with *just* specializations as long as you don’t have multiple template overloads; it seems to agree with my statement that they don’t mix, but its points don’t apply if you just specialize. Forwarding to a class works in all cases, but if you don’t do that either strategy seems to work if you don’t mix them in the wrong way.